# NSSharingService on mountain lion without sharing window

Tags: custom-controls, osx-mountain-lion, sharing, appkit

On mountain lion, I try the new sharing possiblities with the NSSharingService class of AppKit.framework

Everything goes fine with this kind of code

```
NSArray* array = @[ @"myText", [NSImage imageNamed:@"myImageFile"] ];

NSSharingService* sharingServiceFB = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNamePostOnFacebook];

[sharingServiceFB performWithItems:array];
```

But I'd like to do the same without the sharing window generated by the performWithItems function. 
As I'm considering that the user of my application don't want to confirm that he want to send the message as he already have choosen that.
I don't see any "direct posting" function in this class.
Does it need to be done an other way ?

Comment: Did you get any news regarding this topic? I have the same Problem here. I want to share to multiple Services with one click and not present a sheet for every service and force the user to confirm every service.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this other than implementing Facebook's API yourself, but if you don't mind the window appearing for half a second:

```
- (void)whatever {
    NSArray* array = @[ @"myText", [NSImage imageNamed:@"myImageFile"] ];

    NSSharingService* sharingServiceFB = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNamePostOnFacebook];

    [sharingServiceFB performWithItems:array];

    [self performSelector:@selector(pressReturn) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}

- (void)pressReturn {
    CGEventRef keypress = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, 36, TRUE);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, keypress);
}
```

Your users might not like it though...