# Share text in facebook and twitter in cocoa mac OS X application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, macos

[image]

Hi, I am having a cocoa mac application in objective c.

In my app, I want to share text on facebook and twitter like we do in ios with SLComposeViewController.

I searched a lot on google but couldn't find anything for mac application.

I see the above image when I share it from facebook and same for the twitter from one of the mac apps.

How can I achieve the same for my mac application?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you looked at `NSSharingServicePicker` and `NSSharingService` yet?

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer: No, I don't know anything regarding that as I am new to mac development. Can you please solve my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I searched it with @TheAmateurProgrammer's help about `NSSharingService` and `NSSharingServicePicker`.

I found the solution from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053808/nssharingservice-on-mountain-lion-without-sharing-window?rq=1).

**// Facebook**

```
NSArray* array = @[ @"myText"];

NSSharingService* sharingServiceFB = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNamePostOnFacebook];

[sharingServiceFB performWithItems:array];
```

**// Twitter**

```
NSArray* array = @[ @"myText"];

NSSharingService* sharingServiceFB = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNamePostOnTwitter];

    [sharingServiceFB performWithItems:array];
```

Hope it helps someone else also...

Thanks...

Comment: Note: NSSharingServiceNamePostOnTwitter and Facebook and many others have been removed with macOS 10.14 Mojave.